# New vba macro generates error message when fraction is input

Tags: vba

I am trying to have a column automatically format when a fraction is input. Excel by default had been converting the fraction 5/2 to 2.50, which is fine in certain circumstances, but I actually needed it to input what is the Starting Price of a selection, which means if 5/2 is input, the actual calculation would be =5/1+1 (3.50), so it adds in the original stake of 1 as well. 15/8 would be =15/8+1 (2.88) and so on.

In the worksheet, I have the following VBA code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)



    On Error GoTo err_handler



    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Target = Empty Then GoTo exit_handler



    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("Q")) Is Nothing Then

        With Target

            .Formula = Evaluate(.Formula & "+1")

        End With

    End If



exit_handler:

    Application.EnableEvents = True



Exit Sub



err_handler:

    MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description

    Resume exit_handler



End Sub
```

OK, resolved thanks so much. This seems to work perfectly

Comment: "Excel by default had been converting the fraction 5/2 to 2.50" is not correct. It usually "thinks" it is a date and format the cell accordingly... It does what you say, only if you input it like a formula "= 5/2". "5/1+1" instead of "5/2" is really what you mean?  Do you input your data as a formula or simple like 5/2?  How your above function is called?

Comment: At what line does that error appear? I mean, the yellow one... Is your workbook where the code is saved, a .xlsm type?

Comment: Actually FaneDuru, if the cells are formatted as Number, Excel does convert by default. Try it yourself. In a cell that is formatted as number with 2 Decimal places, type 5/2 (not a formula) and it will display 2.50. That is standard behaviour. 
I can't say what line as the box simply pops up when the fraction is input. Yes, the code is saved in the workbook and it is saves as .xlsm

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you understood how exactly to use the function, even if I could be wrong... In order to work as you wish, you must proceed in the next way:

1. Create a `Worksheet_Change` event for the sheet where you intend to work. It will only call your above function.

   `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
       Starting_Price Target
   End Sub`

If you do not know how to create such an event, do not hesitate to ask;

2. Then you must put your above code **in the same sheet module**. Exactly as it is or slightly modified to use only VBA (without RegExp):

   `Private Sub Starting_Price(ByVal Target As Range)
     On Error GoTo err_handler
       Application.EnableEvents = False
       If Target = Empty Then GoTo exit_handler
       If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("P")) Is Nothing Then
           With Target
               If Target.HasFormula Then
                   .Formula = .Formula & "+1"
               End If
           End With
       End If`

   `exit_handler:
       Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
   err_handler:
       MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
       Resume exit_handler
   End Sub`
3. Take care to input (only in column P:P) your fraction like formula: 
   `= 5/2`;
4. Be sure that your Excel workbook is a .xlsm type.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I actually do not wish to input any formula at all; just the fraction. This worksheet will be going to someone who does not understand anything to do with formulas. They will be typing a fraction taken from a website. I wish to keep it as simple as possible for them, so my aim is to have the sheet automatically convert any fraction to a decimal +1; 5/2 becomes 3.50, 7/2 becomes 4.50 and so on. I will redo the code above

Comment: cheers @FanDuru. I actually changed Starting_Price to Worksheet_Change to make it simpler. Your code works well when a formula is input, but I'd like to eliminate the need to have to put =5/2 for a fraction and be just able to type 5/2 or 11/4 or 13/8 and have the result be a decimal +1.

I amended my code above to reflect what you have, but if there is any way  it can be done without the need for a formula, that would be great

cheers

Comment: @honkin: What I wanted to emphasize, was the fact that your previous code **was designed to only works with formulas**. I just read it and tried to make you use it according to its purpose... Can you make me a favor? I would like to know, when you type 5/2 in any cell, except the column to be processed by code, what Excel does display? In my case, Excel guesses that it is a matter of date and automatically transforms the input in a long, equivalent to the specific date number... Probably, it is a matter of localization, bur I would like to learn something from this point of view, al least...

Comment: try this is any cell you like. Format the cell as a number with 2 decimal places. Now type any fraction....5/2, 11/2, 13/8. You will end up with a number with 2 decimal places, rather than a fraction. For me, I was actually looking to have the fraction display as a decimal +1. so 5/2 would be 3.50 rather than 2.50. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, may have posted the answer above where the original code was.

This code seemed to solve the problem, so thanks very much for the input

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)



    On Error GoTo err_handler



    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Target = Empty Then GoTo exit_handler



    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("Q")) Is Nothing Then

        With Target

            .Formula = Evaluate(.Formula & "+1")

        End With

    End If



exit_handler:

    Application.EnableEvents = True



Exit Sub



err_handler:

    MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description

    Resume exit_handler



End Sub
```